# How to display dropdown list instead of buttons when collapsed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.1.3. I have a navbar which displays a horizontal list of buttons, and when collapsed it displays a vertical list of buttons. In version 4.0.0 alpha6 I was able to have the vertical list displayed as a dropdown instead of a list of buttons. Is there any way I can duplicate the 4.0.0 behaviour in 4.1.3? Sample code attached...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Display dropdown list instead of buttons when collapsed</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<h1>Display dropdown list instead of buttons when collapsed</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand"></span>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#navbarSelect" aria-controls="navbarSelect" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSelect">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button1" title="button1" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button2" title="button2" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button3" title="button3" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button4" title="button4" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button5" title="button5" value="Button Text">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<section id="no-more-tables">

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Tasks</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td data-title="Select">
   <div class="form-check">
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="select[1]" name="select[1]">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="select[1]">&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
   </div>
  </td>
    <td data-title="ID"><p class="form-control-static">ADD1</p></td>
    <td data-title="Name"><p class="form-control-static">ADD1 - Insert a single record</p></td>
    <td data-title="Tasks" class="right"><p class="form-control-static">193</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-title="Select">
    <div class="form-check">
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="select[2]" name="select[2]">
     <label class="custom-control-label" for="select[2]">&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
   </div>
  </td>
    <td data-title="ID"><p class="form-control-static">ADD2</p></td>
    <td data-title="Name"><p class="form-control-static">ADD2 - Insert a single record</p></td>
    <td data-title="Tasks" class="right"><p class="form-control-static">227</p></td>
  </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like that [Bootstrap 4 Dropdowns](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

Comment: Any type of dropdown for the vertical list would do, but the horizontal list should still be buttons.